# Juniper network connect authenticates, then says it's not authenticated

Tags: linux, vpn, juniper

I am trying to VPN into my work place. This used to work for me, but now I can't tell what's going on, it just stopped working. I did update my linux box.

I'm running:
juniper network connect v8.0
gentoo linux

```
Passcode: my-pass-code
mkdir(/root/.juniper_networks) failed: Permission denied
20151031170302.836047 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] ncsvc.info New ncsvc log level set to 5 (nccommon.cpp:75)
20151031170302.836174 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] sysdeps.info restoring DNS settings... (sysdeps.cpp:951)
20151031170302.836216 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] sysdeps.error rename /etc/jnpr-nc-resolv.conf => /etc/resolv.conf failed wirh error 2 (sysdeps.cpp:954)
20151031170302.836247 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] sysdeps.error rename /etc/jnpr-nc-hosts.bak => /etc/hosts failed wirh error 2 (sysdeps.cpp:958)
Connecting to vpn.my-place.com : 443
20151031170302.850113 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] ncsvc.info Connecting to vpn.my-place.com:443 (ncsvc.cpp:494)
20151031170302.956606 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] dsclient.para DSClient::authenticate(): user:me, password:..., cert:0, realm:MYVPN (dsclient.cpp:247)
20151031170303.5181 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] DSInet.info IVE host vpn.my-place.com resolved to a.b.c.c, port 443 (dsinet.cpp:311)
20151031170303.5579 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] http_connection.para Starting a timed connect with SSL session 0x94d1e90, proxy (null):0, and timeout 30 (http_connection.cpp:232)
20151031170303.5628 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] http_connection.para Entering state_start_connection (http_connection.cpp:344)
20151031170303.5674 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] http_connection.para Remote Address: ip=a.b.c.c, port=443, familiy=2 (http_connection.cpp:788)
20151031170303.5715 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] http_connection.para Remote Server=vpn.my-place.com (http_connection.cpp:790)
20151031170303.5757 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] http_connection.para Local Address: ip=0.0.0.0, port=0, familiy=2 (http_connection.cpp:795)
20151031170303.5796 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] http_connection.para Proxy Address: ip=(null), port=0, familiy=0 (http_connection.cpp:800)
20151031170303.111713 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] http_connection.para Entering state_continue_connection (http_connection.cpp:361)
20151031170303.111853 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] http_connection.para Entering state_ssl_connect (http_connection.cpp:531)
20151031170303.334069 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] dsssl.para SSL connect ssl=0x94d29b0/sd=3 connection using cipher AES256-SHA (DSSSLSock.cpp:1428)
20151031170303.334388 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] dsssl.error ive_cert_hash = 9adf4asdffadsfa2fas5f2asdfas3e, computed_hash = 9fadfasfdfasdfdasdfa25fasdf37 (DSSSLSock.cpp:1563)
20151031170303.334445 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] http_connection.para Returning DSHTTP_ERROR from state_ssl_connect (http_connection.cpp:546)
20151031170303.334488 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] http_connection.para do_connect error: state 5, err 5 (http_connection.cpp:334)
20151031170303.334730 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] DSInet.error failed to connect to (vpn.my-place.com) error 100005 (dsinet.cpp:383)
20151031170303.334783 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] dsclient.error unable to open URL: (https://vpn.my-place.com/) with error -7 (dsclient.cpp:262)
20151031170303.334823 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] ncapp.error Failed to authenticate with IVE. Error 2 (ncsvc.cpp:225) 
20151031170303.334877 ncsvc[p4202.t4202] dsncuiapi.para DsNcUiApi::~DsNcUiApi (dsncuiapi.cpp:83)
```

The directory /root/.juniper_networks does exist for root user w/ rwx perms, but it still gives that error on line 2. Also, the administrators are telling me that this is successfully authenticating, and it says so in the log above, but then shortly after there are the errors that follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line,

```
  ncsvc[p4202.t4202] dsssl.error ive_cert_hash = 9adf4asdffadsfa2fas5f2asdfas3e, computed_hash = 9fadfasfdfasdfdasdfa25fasdf37 (DSSSLSock.cpp:1563)
```

which indicates a mismatch between the self-signed cert on you server and the one presented to you. You may try checking the certificate installation on your server by going to https://cryptoreport.thawte.com/checker/. Other than that, it looks like a certificate problem, not a connection/permissions/... problem.